# Visual Studio C# String to double without parse

Tags: c#

My teacher expects me to my project without "functions like ToString". I don't want to chance it and use parse, so is there a way to send a string to double? I am making a calculator.

```
    private void btnln_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Store.Length > 0) //Check if store is longer than 0
        {
            double x = double.Parse(Store); //Put store into a double
            Store = ""; //Clear store
            Store += Math.Log(x); //Natural logarithm
            lblNumbers.Text = Store; //Update numbers label
        }
    }
```

So I would like the line 
double x = double.Prase(Store); 
to be replaced

Comment: Your edit did not made question any more clear... What's wrong with `double.Parse`? (also showed some effort - that's always welcome)

Comment: My teacher does not want me to use functions like "ToString". Im going to assume he doesn't want me to use parse either @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: Still it is unclear what you are asking for. If you want someone to write that function for you - there are plenty of *other* sites devoted to writing code for someone, including some specific for homework. There is really no alternative function as it is pointless to have several functions doing the same thing (indeed there is `TryParse` which is essentially the same as `Parse` but not throwing exceptions for invalid values) - so there is not much SO can offer at this point.

Comment: If your teacher does not explicitly say that he doesn't want you to use parse, then don't assume that he doesn't want you to.